# sharepoint search 2010 crawl xml files

Tags: search

we have xml files in external folder and we are crawling the folder in search configuration.How can I crawl XML files and map node values to properties?
 For example I have a node called "Bussinesslogic" and want to query all xml files with a specific businesslogic property. Is this possible in sharepoint 2010 out-of-the box? Do I have to write an extension in c#?

Comment: You would need an ifilter for this vik, possibly a self built one, if you google xml ifilters and look at paid ones, you might find one already, but there are guides on how to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link ..
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102114339/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/06/04/creating-a-bcs-based-search-connector-framework.aspx)

Rajeev

Comment: please dont just post links, instead post a short description of the solution and *then* link. External links (especially blogs) tend to be short lived, and we really like to keep the solution inside our site! Fix please :)